# FRM-40735: post-insert trigger raised unhandled exception ora-01722

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I create POST-INSERT Trigger on Block when I am getting this error on Oracle Forms 11gR2

"FRM-40735: post-insert trigger raised unhandled exception ora-01722"

**POST-INSERT Trigger Code:**

```
Insert into we_group (GROUP_ID, GROUP_SIZE, NRSP_STATUS, GROUP_RECEIVED)
Select DISTINCT GROUP_ID, ('Select COUNT(*) from we_group_hof_k'), 
nrsp_status, sysdate
from we_group_hof_k;

commit_form;
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove ' to prevent number to char convertion

```
 Select DISTINCT GROUP_ID, (select COUNT(*) from we_group_hof_k), 
 nrsp_status, sysdate
 from we_group_hof_k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using analytic version of the `COUNT` function (if Forms version you use supports it; 10g doesn't, I can't tell about 11g):

```
INSERT INTO we_group (GROUP_ID,
                      group_size,
                      nrsp_status,
                      group_received)
   SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_ID,
                   COUNT (*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL),
                   nrsp_status,
                   SYSDATE
     FROM we_group_hof_k;
```

Answer (score 0):

*It evidently seems `ORA-01722` raises due to an attempt to insert a quoted string*

*( `'Select COUNT(*) from we_group_hof_k'` ) into a numeric column( `GROUP_SIZE` ).*

So, first of all you need to get rid of those quotes, and even whole sub-select, since you already try to select from the same table in the main query, and just consider to include a `group by` clause instead:

```
Insert Into we_group(group_id, group_size, nrsp_status, group_received)
  Select group_id,Count(1),nrsp_status, sysdate
    From we_group_hof_k
   Group By group_id,nrsp_status;
```

Lastly do not use a `commit` or `commit_form` inside a `POST-INSERT` trigger, that usage is considered as illegal restricted there.